# Crossreference \lstinputlisting code

Tags: cross-referencing, listings, code

I frequently need to put C code into my document, so I defined,

```
\newcommand{\Ccode}[1]{\lstinputlisting[backgroundcolor=\color{gray!5},caption=\texttt{\lstname},language=C]{C/#1}}
```

in my document preamble. I have a directory called `C`, where I have all my `C` source code, so I just import those code into my document using this,

```
\Ccode{screen_buffer.c}
```

Now, in my document, I want to refer to one of my code using `\label{}` and `\ref{}` but I don't know where to put the `\label{}`. So, how do I cross reference my code, if it is possible at all.

**EDIT:** My document is

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\title{Computational Physics}
\author{Ayatana}
\usepackage{listings, xcolor}

\newcommand{\Ccode}[1]{
    \lstinputlisting[backgroundcolor=\color{gray!5},
    caption=\texttt{\lstname},language=C]{C/#1}
}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code}
\lstset{
    frame=single,
    breaklines=true,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\color{gray}\small\texttt,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    columns=fullflexible,
    showstringspaces=false
    captionpos=b,
}

\begin{document}
The \texttt{Hello World} code in C programming language goes like this,
\Ccode{hello.c}
\end{document}
```

`pdflatex` rendered like this,
[image: pdftlatex rendering]

Now I want to refer to the above code using `\ref{}`. So, where do I put `\label{}`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a working document, not just fragments of code. The `listings` environment has a `label` key option, as far as I know

Comment: Typical problem of macros. They can be handy, but can make loss of functionality. You need to extend the macro `Ccode` to have an optional argument (which takes your label). Or simply define the label to have the same name as the file that is input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The label is possible with `label=...`. I suggest to use an optional argument to `\Ccode` where the label can be specified (and #2 is for the external code file)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\title{Computational Physics}
\author{Ayatana}
\usepackage{listings, xcolor}

\newcommand{\Ccode}[2][]{
    \lstinputlisting[backgroundcolor=\color{gray!5},
    caption=\texttt{\lstname},language=C,#1]{#2}
}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code}
\lstset{
    frame=single,
    breaklines=true,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\color{gray}\small\texttt,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    columns=fullflexible,
    showstringspaces=false
    captionpos=b,
}

\begin{document}
The \texttt{Hello World} code in C programming language goes like this,
\Ccode[label={myhello}]{hello.c}

In listing \ref{myhello} we see


\end{document}
```